# Google charts number range filter doesn't work properly with accordions

Tags: filter, google-visualization, range, jquery-ui-accordion

Google charts range filter works perfectly fine outside of accordion. The default range sliders are set at left most and right most. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/samsumi007/1v5xyqL9/

But the sliders get messed up when i put this google chart inside of accordion. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/samsumi007/k1cvd05m/ (Check Section 2)

```
<html>

<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
            'packages': ['controls']
        });

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

        // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
        // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
        // passes in the data and draws it.
        function drawDashboard() {

            // Create our data table.
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
                ['Michael', 5],
                ['Elisa', 7],
                ['Robert', 3],
                ['John', 2],
                ['Jessica', 6],
                ['Aaron', 1],
                ['Margareth', 8]
            ]);

            // Create a dashboard.
            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

            // Create a range slider, passing some options
            var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
                    'containerId': 'filter_div',
                    'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten'
                }
            });

            // Create a pie chart, passing some options
            var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'PieChart',
                    'containerId': 'chart_div',
                    'options': {
                    'width': 600,
                        'height': 600,
                        'pieSliceText': 'value',
                        'legend': 'right'
                }
            });

            // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
            // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
            // given the chosen slider range.
            dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);

            // Draw the dashboard.
            dashboard.draw(data);
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                active: false,
                alwaysOpen: false,
                fillspace: false,
                collapsible: true,
                navigation: true,
                heightStyle: "content" //auto, fill, conten
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="accordion">
         <h3>Section 1</h3>

        <div></div>
         <h3>Section 2</h3>

        <div id="dashboard_div" style='height:900px;'>
            <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
            <div id="filter_div"></div>
            <div id="chart_div"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am not sure why it's behaving like this. Even though its displaying the correct data, the left and right sliders are set at '0' which doesn't make sense to user reading the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem is your accordion is making the display hidden so when it tries to set the state of the control, it thinks the width available is 0 (you see your data correctly because the state is acually in 8). Can only think of 2 ways of fixing it:

1) After the first click on the chart section, set the correct width and left style properties for the state >> a bit hard (or just draw the chart after the section 2 has been clicked)

2) Make the accordion only after the chart has finished rendering:

```
<script>
var firstTimeLoaded=true;
//your code...

if (firstTime) { // if its the first time it draws, add the accordion
                    google.visualization.events.addListener(dashboard, 'ready', function() {
                        $("#accordion").accordion({
                            autoHeight: false,
                            active: false,
                            alwaysOpen: false,
                            fillspace: false,
                            collapsible: true,
                            navigation: true,
                            heightStyle: "content" //auto, fill, conten
                        });
                        google.visualization.events.removeAllListeners(dashboard) // remove listener
                    })
                }
dashboard.draw(data);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k1cvd05m/1/